# Find orders in the last 12 months, max date being the last order date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I feel like this question has been asked before, I couldn't find the exact requirement or the database engine (PostgreSQL), so please feel free to link me to the original.

I have a seemingly simple requirement: given an `orders` table, I need to find orders in a 12-month range, but the ending date will be the max date found in the table. The column of interest is called `order_date` and stores dates in the `YYYY-mm-dd` format.

So, here's my attempt, but it fails, saying that the aliased column (`max_order_date`) doesn't exist:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_date BETWEEN
    (SELECT max(order_date) FROM orders as max_order_date)
        AND (SELECT max_order_date - INTERVAL '1 year');
```

After seeing Postgres complain, I tried to write the query without an alias:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_date BETWEEN
    (SELECT max(order_date) FROM orders as max_order_date)
        AND (SELECT max(order_date) - INTERVAL '1 year');
```

Only this time, I got this error: `aggregate functions are not allowed in the WHERE clause`.

I obviously am looking for the right way to do this query, but am also very eager to learn why the above two limitations exist. That is, why can't the aliasing work in the first case, and why aggregates aren't allowed in `WHERE`? To me it doesn't look like I'm asking for something twisted or impossible to compute.

Thank you!

Comment: Not directly related to your question but just a point of interest. Your statement  *stores dates in the `YYYY-mm-dd` format* is incorrect. All dates are stored in an internal structure (bigint?) which you basically never have to worry about, provided you process with just date routines. So the converted values `date '2021-09-18'` and `to_date('18092021',ddmmyyyy')` are internally and stored exactly the same - as date data type. Try the following: Select date '2021-09-18' = to_date('18092021','ddmmyyyy');

Comment: @Belayer Ah, very true. I've been a MySQL user so was under the impression that I was looking at strings. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably more efficient using a subquery:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where o.order_date >= (select max(order_date) - interval '1 year' from orders);
```

Both the subquery and the outer query can use an index on `orders(order_date)`.

Comment: This is much cleaner but also leaves me thinking how I'd handle it if I needed the dates to be in a range, e.g., from -2 years to -1 year since the last order date. 

Comment: @ankush981 . . . (1) That is not the question you asked.  (2) There is probably a simple solution to using a range as well.

Comment: Hey, sorry, I didn't mean to impose anything on you! I was just thinking aloud. 

Answer (score 1):

You can use the analytical function of max() over() to determine the max order date and then use a filter to check if the order date lies between 1 year and max order date.

```
select * 
  from (SELECT o.*
              ,max(order_date) over(partition by 1) as max_order_date
         FROM orders o 
       )x
where order_date>= x.max_order_date - INTERVAL '1 year'
```

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer as this works but it appears I need to learn two new things now -- `over` and `partition`. 